# Temporary version of ggplot `theme_set(theme_gray(base_size = 22))`

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want the first plot to be font size 22 for all elements. I can achieve this via `theme_set(theme_gray(base_size = 22))`. I want the second plot to return to the default sizes, which I've done below. The Question - Is there an alternative command to `theme_set(theme_gray(base_size = 22))` that I can use on the first plot, which will free me from having to reset the value back to normal values on the subsequent plots?

```
library(ggplot2)

# First plot with base size of 22
theme_set(theme_gray(base_size = 22))
ggplot(mpg, aes(hwy)) + geom_density()

# Second plot, which I want to return to the default size 10
theme_set(theme_gray(base_size = 10))
ggplot(mpg, aes(hwy)) + geom_histogram()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the size of the text for a specific graph by adjusting the `theme`.  Here's an example:

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
geom_point() +
theme(text = element_text(size = 22))

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species)) +
geom_bar()
```

[image]
[image]